# What about vedantas of previous kali yuga?

Tags: vedanta

Vedantas of previous kaliyuga or yugas we have description of previous kaliyugas and yugas do we have any mention of vedantas of previous kaliyuga or yuga

Comment: Can you please clarify your question? ([Edit] to add some details.)

Comment: I don't think there is any mention of Yugas in Vedanta. But if there are any such yuga system in Kaliyuga, then definitely there is no reason for any Vedanta to not exist, given that we already have much Vedanta this yuga only that we are still confused which version is right and which version isn't.